# SSH crash on startup

Tags: ssh, vps, upstart

My connection ssh to my VPS is not working anymore, i checked the auth.log file and found this :

auth.log

```
Jul 28 20:22:04 warp sshd[31257]: Accepted password for root from MY_IP port 49196 ssh2
Jul 28 20:23:01 warp CRON[31385]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:23:01 warp CRON[31385]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:23:26 warp sshd[31411]: error: rexec of /usr/sbin/sshd failed: No such file or directory
Jul 28 20:23:28 warp sshd[31411]: Accepted password for root from MY_IP port 49229 ssh2
Jul 28 20:24:01 warp CRON[31473]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:24:01 warp CRON[31473]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:25:01 warp CRON[31584]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:25:01 warp CRON[31585]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:25:01 warp CRON[31584]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:25:01 warp CRON[31586]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user munin by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:25:01 warp CRON[31585]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:25:01 warp CRON[31586]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user munin
Jul 28 20:26:01 warp CRON[31680]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:26:01 warp CRON[31680]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:27:01 warp CRON[31724]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:27:01 warp CRON[31724]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:28:01 warp CRON[31883]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jul 28 20:28:01 warp CRON[31883]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jul 28 20:28:08 warp sshd[31886]: error: rexec of /usr/sbin/sshd failed: No such file or directory
Jul 28 20:28:12 warp sshd[31886]: Invalid user ssh root from MY_IP 
Jul 28 20:28:12 warp sshd[31886]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ssh root [preauth]
Jul 28 20:28:16 warp sshd[31886]: error: Could not get shadow information for NOUSER
Jul 28 20:28:16 warp sshd[31886]: Failed password for invalid user ssh root from MY_IP  port 50247 ssh2
Jul 28 20:28:19 warp sshd[31886]: Failed password for invalid user ssh root from MY_IP  port 50247 ssh2
Jul 28 20:28:24 warp sshd[31886]: Failed password for invalid user ssh root from MY_IP  port 50247 ssh2
Jul 28 20:28:26 warp sshd[31886]: Connection closed by MY_IP  [preauth]
Jul 28 20:28:26 warp sshd[31893]: error: rexec of /usr/sbin/sshd failed: No such file or directory
Jul 28 20:28:28 warp sshd[31893]: Invalid user ssh root from MY_IP 
Jul 28 20:28:28 warp sshd[31893]: input_userauth_request: invalid user ssh root [preauth]
Jul 28 20:28:28 warp sshd[31893]: Failed none for invalid user ssh root from MY_IP  port 50249 ssh2
```

This is the last logs of my server. It seems like i get connected for the last time 2 months ago Jul 28 20:22:04.
And i tried few minutes later unsucessfully due to an issue "No such file or directory in /usr/bin/sshd"

Answer (score 1):

Well... does that file still exist?  If it is, it's likely one or more of its shared libraries have gone missing (annoyingly, `execve`() produces the same error for both "the binary is missing" and "a shared library is missing"), which you can check with `ldd /usr/sbin/sshd`.

Chances are, either someone's mangled the OS, or you've had a catastrophic existence failure of a crucial part of a filesystem.  Either way, you're probably about to discover exactly how good, bad, or otherwise your backups are.